# EJBCA adminweb Authorization denied

Tags: certificate, authorization, ca

I am currently testing with EJBCA while having a problem in accessing the administration page.

The EJBCA-4.0.13 is running on CentOS 6.2, with apache-ant-1.8.4, jboss-5.1.0-GA, mysql and mysql-connector-java. Installation is OK and no error occured in the jboss server log and I can access the EJBCA public web page with the url: https://:8443/ejbca. While I cannot access the administration page(https://:8443/ejbca/adminweb) with this information:

Authorization Denied
Cause: Your certificate is revoked or cannot be located in the database.

Any idea will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done in `LocalCertificateStoreSessionBean.authenticate` method. This could mean that you have not properly generated SuperAdmin certificate, or it is revoked, timed out or is issued by another CA that EJBACA's AdminCA.

Check your `superadmin.p12` with:

```
openssl pkcs12 -nokeys -in ./superadmin.p12 -out superadmin.pem
openssl x509 -in ./superadmin.pem -text
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have solved this issue by re-installing. And it works fine now.